# ¿Cómo utilizar la etiqueta <script> con typescript?

Tags: html, typescript

Quiero incrustar código `typescript` dentro de las etiquetas `<script>` en un html, algo como esto:

```html
<script type = "text/typescript">
</script>
```

He visto algunos compiladores que pasan el código a javascript y me permiten usar dichas etiquetas, como por ejemplo : https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile. Sin embargo no me funciona descargue los scripts y los agrege en el body pero aún así no funciona y tampoco me arroja error, no sé si exista otra manera de realizar esto?

Comment: ¿Qué código llevas hecho? ¿Qué error te da? ¿Has mirado el código fuente de la live demo del sitio web que has puesto? http://niutech.github.com/typescript-compile/demo/demo.html Ahí tienen un ejemplo funcionando

Comment: si... revise el ejemplo, y en el repo los archivos..... al principio estaba ubicando los tags en el header pero luego los cambie al body, pero no funciona...... nisiquiera me arroja error

Answer (score 4):

"Esta es una versión que escribí que usa directamente la versión de Microsoft / TypeScript / master para que siempre esté actualizada: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script"

Esta pregunta fue respondida anteriormente. Te dejo el enlace para que veas si te sirve algo mas de allí, pero preguntaron lo mismo. Saludos
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015899/embed-typescript-code-in-an-html-document

Créditos a: [basarat user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat)